# Setup CLANG 3.4 on Code::blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clang++

I downloaded Clang 3.4 for windows from the following website: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html

---

I am trying to fix the settings for code::blocks (**see Image**)
[image]

1. Are these settings correct?
2. What should I put for Resource compiler and Make Program? should I leave them empty?
3. TO modify settings click on set on default

Build log still indicates that I am using GCC compilet and not clang
[image]

Comment: What happened when you _simply tried it_?

Comment: The settings are all correct from what I can see, but you will likely not have a lot of fun with it. CLang is far from being operative at this time. At least not by downloading the release and unpacking a zip file. There is no LibC++ and no Win32 API, any such thing as `#include <someting c++>` will fail. You can probably get a working compiler installed somehow, but it does not seem to be all that simple. Some _theory_ that I've heard is you need to copy over glibc++ and rebuild the MinGW API using CLang, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Copying over everything from MinGW as-is won't work by the way, since the ABI is incompatible. So, still some work ahead.

Comment: oh ok @Damon. I thought that It contained all the features of GCC. Well i'll get back to the GCC compiler then. I don't want to complicate my life right now. Better stick to GCC. I just wanted to test Clang because I saw that it's  faster than GCC.

Comment: It's a different compiler that aims to be a more or less drop-in replacement for GCC, but that doesn't mean that it contains everything of GCC, nor does it mean that it will work out of the box on every platform. All I can tell is that under Windows, it isn't as easy as downloading a zip file and there you go (apparently it is just that simple under Linux, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you. Do you want to use those applications for those tasks? As far as I am aware, you should not have any compatibility issues — MinGW Make just makes system calls, so it will be able to invoke either MinGW GCC, or Clang, just the same.

Comment: @Hani "When i compile it that's what i get" I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Build log indicates that I am still using the GCC compiler and not Clang. Please check image...

Comment: @HaniGoc: That's about selecting the right build configuration. You've not done that. However, you _have_ set up the LLVD build configuration correctly, from what I can tell. Next time please post all relevant detail on your question from the start, because it's been really hard to tell what you wanted here.